# what is alternative in bigtable to hbase bulkload

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

We are planning to migrate from hbase to bigtable. We used bulkload to load large amount of data. The bulkload is efficient and it is able to ensure Idempotency. How to achieve the efficiency and update idempotency via bigtable? Do you have any recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

You can upload your HBase data to Cloud Storage and then import it to Cloud BigTable using Dataflow. For this you can use the already [existing templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch) depending on the file type you export the data to.

Comment: do you know whether there is any update idempotency for dataflow?

Comment: Google-provided templates are already idempotent.